# How to test selecting values from dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, unit-testing

I have a file abc.py:

```
import pandas as pd

df_names= pd.DataFrame()

def get_index_value(given_id):
    return df_names.index[df_names["name"] == given_id].tolist()[0]
```

Before calling get_index_value(), df_names dataframe is filled with content - few rows with "name" and "name_id" columns.

How do I test the get_value function? I tried to solve this in many ways, the closest I got was:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import pandas as pd
from abc import get_index_value

class GetIndexVaueTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch("abc.df_names")
    def test_get_index_value(self, df_names_mock):
        columns = ["name", "name_id"]
        data = [["a", 1], ["b",2]]

        df_names_mock.return_value = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)

        given_id = 2
        expected = 1
        result = get_index_value(given_id)
        self.assertEqual(expected, result)
```

What I get is a failed test and info:

```
<MagicMock name='df_names.index.__getitem__().tolist().__getitem__()' id='1984241783184'> != 1
```

Why do I have a MagicMock object insted of a result I was expecting? How can I make the test work?